# Java, swt and web

Tags: java

How to retrieve all images from a site. I want to make desktop application which show images of a cars received by a web site.

Comment: Does the site provide an API for this? Does the site's terms of usage allow this kind of application to be developed? Do the image URL:s follow a certain pattern or do you require screen scraping?

Comment: There is no API and I don't require screen scraping. I just have to load some pictures,like car images, from some website. I know how to get a picture by url but how to get the all images is something which I don't know.

Comment: This question is more about ethics than "How".
If the copyright owner allows you to download the images, then most probably he would have provided an API/ or other ways to download them.

If you have control of the website, you may add/request to add such a service.

If that is not possible, you may be doing some illegal activities. Please check that aspect too.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do is get the HTML from the site you're connecting to and search for all the `<img>` tags, parse the url out of them, and then loop through each url, connect to it, download the image, then use your app to view the images.

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=java+download+url+to+file&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) is loaded with examples how to download files from urls.

Comment: OK but what are we doing if the website contain a lot of pages and only 4 of them have pictures with <img> tag?

Comment: You'll have to take that into consideration. Link from page to page and keep adding each found image url to a list of image urls. If the page doesn't have any img tags, then add nothing to the list and link to the next page.

Comment: This is a good idea and the only thing which I need is a HTML Parser.

Comment: For what you are doing, it wouldn't be all that hard to write your own. In this case you could even use regex to quickly find the tags you need.